# python iterate and change string

Tags: python

```
s = "fff555#$%^"
f =filter(str.isalpha, s)
print("f", f)
```

I thought I could iterate over `s` and filter each character in `s` by `str.isalpha` function.

I do not want to use regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to join after filtering, as filter returns a generator.

```
s = "fff555#$%^"
f = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, s))
print("f", f)
```

Comment: Where would one find documentation regarding "generator". The docs I followed stated: "filter - Construct a list from those element"...

Comment: @Paul The behavior of `filter` changed in Python 3. See the [Python 3 docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)